# Elastic search score/sorting - rotating categories

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents like this ( simplified case of course):

```
Category: A, Rating: 10
Category: A, Rating: 9
Category: A, Rating: 5

Category: B, Rating: 8
Category: B, Rating: 5
Category: B, Rating: 4
Category: B, Rating: 1

Category: C, Rating: 9
Category: C, Rating: 8
Category: C, Rating: 3
Category: C, Rating: 2
```

We can assume that category can be also numeric, it does not matter for me.

What I need to achieve it to sort result by:

rotated types -> ABC ABC ABC and when some type is "finished" ( lets assume A) then for example BC BC BC and then when B is finished just some more C C C

secondary condition is rating and we want to sort from highest to lowest

So example of expected output would be:

```
Category: A, Rating: 10
Category: B, Rating: 8
Category: C, Rating: 9

Category: A, Rating: 9
Category: B, Rating: 5
Category: C, Rating: 8

Category: A, Rating: 5
Category: B, Rating: 4
Category: C, Rating: 3

Category: B, Rating: 1
Category: C, Rating: 2
```

Does anyone have any hint how to achieve it?

I try playing with function_score and multiple script_score option but not luck.

My idea at some point was to give each category a number and than somehow increment it ( but how? ) so for example A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 and documents with A get scores like 11, 210, 31, 41 and so on, B -> 12, 22, 32, 42 , C -> 13, 23, 33, 43 etc and but I cannot get to satisfying solution.

Maybe someone will have some other idea? Any ideas are appreciated.

Btw, real case there will be more sorting/scoring criteria than just one rating. I simplified it right now for this case.

Comment: I think of another approach. Maybe you could, in your request, manage each category one by one, and merge results in a simple code at the application side?

Comment: I forgot to mention in my main post that there is pagination there which makes it much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything to do this natively, but to extend Jaycreation 's solution, I would suggest using search collapsing on the category field and ordering the collapsed section by rating. In your app, you can just round robin through the groups until you run out of one type.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/collapse-search-results.html

Answer (score 0):

ELasticsearch doesn't supports this type of behaviour by default, so we have to do it on the application layer after fetching the results from Elasticsearch. First of all we fetch all the possible results for given category using `filter` functionality. So the above approach will yield us a list namely `category_a_list`, `category_b_list`, `category_c_list`, ... and so on.

Now I am not sure as to which languge you are using to build the solution, so I will provide pseudo code in Python which you can later translate.

```py
# First create an array of all the results retrived
all_category_list = [category_a_list, category_b_list, category_c_list]
result = []
counter = 0
while True:
    idx = counter % len(all_category_list)
    if len(all_category_list[idx]) > 0:
        # Pop the first element and append to results
        result.append(all_category_list[idx][0])
        all_category_list[idx][0].pop(0)
    if check_all_category_list_empty(all_category_list):
        break
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem is pagination.  I thought that I added this info but clearly not,, sorry :(

 If there would be no pagination I would simply do it in PHP.

But there is a lot of items and I need 6 at a time with limit and offset.

Right now only idea I have correct "rank"  in PHP and put it to elastic and then get it from elastic based on that.